# Referencing issue with ActionListener class

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

I have problem referencing the Timer to the ActionListener class. I want to stop the timer after Java displays the dialog box that displays the time and starts again after clicking on "Yes".

This is what I currently have:

```
public class AlarmClock 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean status = true;

        Timer t = null;

        ActionListener listener = new TimePrinter(t);
        t = new Timer(10000, listener);

        t.start();

        while(status)
        {
        } 
    }
}

class TimePrinter implements ActionListener
{   
    Timer t;

    public TimePrinter(Timer t)
    {
        this.t = t;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {   
        t.stop();                //To stop the timer after it displays the time

        Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.");

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "The time now is "+time.format(now)+"\nSnooze?", "Alarm Clock", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if(choice == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Snooze activated.");
            t.start();           //To start the timer again
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code gives a null pointer exception error. Is there any other way I can reference the Timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a chicken-and-egg problem here, since the constructors of both classes require a reference to each other.  You need to break the cycle somehow, the easiest way would be to construct the `Timer` without a listener, then construct the listener, then add it to the timer:

```
    t = new Timer(10000, null);
    ActionListener l = new TimePrinter(t);
    t.addActionListener(l);
```

Alternatively, you could add a setter to `TimePrinter` instead of passing the `Timer` to its constructor:

```
class TimePrinter implements ActionListener
{   
    Timer t;

    public TimePrinter() {}

    public setTimer(Timer t)
    {
        this.t = t;
    }
```

and then do

```
    TimePrinter listener = new TimePrinter();
    t = new Timer(10000, listener);
    listener.setTimer(t);
```

Either way the end result is the same.

Comment: Had the exact same chicken-and-egg problem, this is a great solution, thanks!